# c# xml serialization extra root node

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a collection that I want to serialize to an xml document. The class is:

```
public class Contacts{
  public List<PendingContactDTO> contacts { get; set; } 
}
```

My main problem is that now my xml looks

```
<Contacts>
   <contacts>
       <..... all contacts>
   </contacts>
</Contacts>
```

The thing is, I want to look it like this:

```
   <contacts>
       <..... all contacts>
   </contacts>
```

Is there a way to this?

Comment: It does model exactly what you've got, a Contacts property in a Contacts class. What should it be when the class gets extra members?

Comment: @Henk that scenario is well-defined; simply, you might get `<a/><b/><b/><b/><b/><c/>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("contacts")]
public class Contacts{
    [XmlElement("contact")]
    public List<PendingContactDTO> contacts { get; set; } 
}
```

should give you:

```
<contacts>
     <contact...>...</contact>
     ...
     <contact...>...</contact>
</contacts>
```

(the `XmlRootAttribute` renames the `Contacts` to `contacts`; the `XmlElementAttribute` tells it to remove the extra layer for the collection node, naming each `contact`)

Comment: @PopCatalin I was not allowed to do it then, because I had to wait some more time after asking the question ;) Had it listed on my todo.

Answer (score 0):

load your xml in to `XmlDocument`

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(StrXML);
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Contacts/contacts")
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: The OP is trying to *create* an xml document of the given shape... not to *parse* one